# C++, Qt Signals & slots

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to understand Qt 4.8 signals and slots so I wrote some code to test it out for myself. Eventually, I want to be able to use a common source file in my project so that serial ports can be accessed from any source file in the project.

I set up a Qt GUI application and added a C++ class header and source file, shown below.

When I try to build, I get the error message when I try to emit the signal.

> /home/user/QTProjects/stest1/stest1/ser.cpp:25: error: invalid use of 'this' in non-member function

I haven't even gotten to the stage of setting up the connections yet!

My newbie status is obvious, I'd be grateful for any help.

Thanks,
James

---

The following is the MainWindow.cpp:-

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "ser.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ser *j = new ser;
    j->init();

    connect (this, SIGNAL(click()), ser, SLOT(testprint()));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QByteArray ba1;

    ba1.resize(6);
    ba1[0]='H'; ba1[1]='e'; ba1[2]='l'; ba1[3]='l'; ba1[4]='o'; ba1[5]='\n';

    this->printtext(ba1);
}

void MainWindow::printtext(const QByteArray &data)
{
    ui->textEdit->insertPlainText(QString(data));
}
```

The following is the MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void printtext(const QByteArray &data);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

signals:
//    void click;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

The following is ser.cpp:-

```
#include "ser.h"

#include <QObject>

ser::ser(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void ser::init()
{

 //   connect(this->, SIGNAL(testsignal), MainWindow, SLOT(printtext(const QByteArray &data)));

}

void ser::testprint()
{
    QByteArray ba1;

    ba1.resize(8);
    ba1[0]='S'; ba1[1]= '0'; ba1[2]= ' '; ba1[3]= 'l'; ba1[4]='o'; ba1[5]='n'; ba1[6]='g'; ba1[7]='\n';

    emit this->testsignal(ba1);
}
```

The following is ser.h

```
#ifndef SER_H
#define SER_H
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QObject>

class ser : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ser(QObject *parent = 0);

    void init();

signals:
    void testsignal(const QByteArray &data);

private slots:
    void testprint();


public slots:


};

#endif // SER_H
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is implemented as `void testprint() { ... }`, but it should be `void ser::testprint() { ... }`. It's in your cpp file.

Also note that you don't need to use `this->` to refer to class members. `emit testsignal(ba1);` will fork fine.

Comment: OK, I fixed that and added a connect statement to MainWindow.cpp. The error is from the *connect* statement. 

> /home/user/QTProjects/stest1/stest1/mainwindow.cpp:14: error: expected
> primary-expression before ',' token

I can't figure out what the sender is supposed to be. Can anyone guide me as to what both of the connect statements should be?

James

Comment: You should use your object `j` in `connect`. You're trying to use the class name `ser` instead.

Comment: Great, that worked.     My next problem is connecting the signal in ser to the slot in the MainWindow. I used

Answer (score 2):

I think should be

```
connect (this, SIGNAL(click()), j, SLOT(testprint()));
```

instead of

```
connect (this, SIGNAL(click()), ser, SLOT(testprint()));
```

that apart, I can't spot where you connect `testsignal`

Answer (score 0):

Great, that worked. 
`connect (this, SIGNAL(click()), j, SLOT(testprint()));`

My next problem is connecting the signal in ser to the slot in the MainWindow. I used

```
connect(j,
        SIGNAL(testsignal),
        this,
        SLOT(printtext(const QByteArray &data)));
```

It was inserted immediately after the other connect statement.
This does not print out the expected message "Slong". It also does not give me any error! What is the problem? 
James

Comment: the format of `StackOverflow` isn't a forum with threads where follow-up questions appear as posts. Rather, it is a question-answer site: one question, then (potentially multiple) answers. If you need more info, the right thing to do is open a new question. In addition, if your questions get answered, you should mark ("accept") the best/most helpful answer with a checkmark to indicate that your problem is solved.